# In ruby from class with function without self how to get current class name?

Tags: ruby

how is is possible in the below example to print `ValidatorStatus` class name?

```
class ValidatorStatus
  def initialize(host, msg)
    @host = host
    @msg = msg
  end

  attr_accessor :host
  attr_accessor :msg

  def to_s
    puts %|How to have this print *ValidatorStatus*
           by dynamically discovering class name?
           also if im a subclass of this should print
           the subclass name|
  end 
end
```

Comment: The claim “without self” is absurd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.class.name
```

Does just what you want. But as you added the restriction not to use `self`:

```
public_send(:class).name
```

Comment: ... which of course *implicitly* uses `self` as well, as it is just syntactic sugar for `self.public_send(:class).name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def to_s
  self.class.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the correct answer is `self.class.name`

If you want to get creative, you could use :

```
class A
  def to_s
    Module.nesting.first.to_s
  end
end

puts A.new
# A
```

There's no `self` here, not even an implicit, hidden one.

It doesn't return the subclass though:

```
class B < A
end

puts B.new
# A
```

Another possibility would be to parse the current file :

```
class C < A
  def to_s
    File.readlines(__FILE__).take(__LINE__).reverse.join[/(?<=^class )\w+/]
  end
end

puts C.new
# C
```

Comment: I like the last one best. Brute force FTW.